# Can I do if/then replacement with a single mod_rewrite regex rule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I had a single domain with 4 localised versions of each page. 4 separate domains have now been provisioned, 1 for each locality. I would like to create a mod_rewrite rule to permanently redirect to the new domains. I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^(au|nz|uk|us)/(.*) https://www.example.com.$1/$2 [R=301]
```

which will do conversions like:

```
example.com/au/testpage    to    example.com.au/testpage
example.com/nz/testpage    to    example.com.nz/testpage
```

The problem with the above is that example.com.nz needs to be example.co.nz. Is there some regex I can use to simultaneously convert

```
www.example.com/au    to    www.example.com.au
www.example.com/nz    to    www.example.co.nz
www.example.com/uk    to    www.example.co.uk
www.example.com/us    to    www.example.us
```

Comment: You're essentially trying to conditionally insert characters that don't come from a match in the input string, so I doubt a pure regex solution is possible - I'd just use two rules instead and not worry about it.

Comment: sorry, didn't get the question. Regex are used to match *patterns*, that's it. As @CertainPerformance commented above, it's certainly impossible a solution than only use regular expressions. Maybe a regex to match all of those valid address and then a map is the best solution..

Comment: You might be able to use [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) rather than just `RewriteRule`, though

Comment: I considered RewriteMap when reading through the documentation earlier, but still thought there may be a purely regex solution. Thanks for that, I will look into it. The above is just one example, in reality I'm looking at either 12 rewrite rules (3 for each domain) or with RewriteMap I should be able to get it down to 3 rules, with the domain component being variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think If the regex `if/else` logic will work here but If your `nz` domain needs to be redirected to a different location , you can use a new rule to handle it

```
RewriteRule ^nz/(.*)$ http://example.co.nz/$1 [L,R]
```